# UWP C++ project call Windows API using assembly language

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, uwp

Is it possible to make Windows API calls from assembly language in an UWP C++ project?

UWP includes the library *WindowsApp.lib* in it's Windows SDK. But I don't want to call any of the Win32 and COM APIs functions.

At this stage I'm only interested in the new Windows 10 functions.

E.g.

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()
```

Some background... assembly language is working in my UWP C++ project. For example, the project contains an .asm (masm) file which has a trivial function with two parameters. This asm function gets called successfully from C++ and returns a value which gets displayed on the front-end via XAML.

Now I'm trying to learn the next step with API calls.

Comment: You can obviously write that first in C++ and then check in disassembly how it gets compiled, but just studying used calling convention (some x86-64 windows ABI), and the functions prototypes in C and their data structures definitions, should be enough for calling from asm. The C++ disassembly can be used to verify you understand it well and it works as you expect. (unless this is some C# / CXX stuff, I don't know what UWP is, and if it provides C/C++ API entry points, those should be usable from asm in the same way as C or C++ does use them).

Comment: And I **guess** (I don't use/code_for windows for 10+ years) you can't avoid Win32 API at least for loading the UWP library and dynamically linking against it, that's probably what your C++ app does during init phase. But that's probably OK I guess, as you can't load the UWP library/DLL without Win OS API.